# Is it possible to have a typescript only npm package?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I have a project which is only ever meant to be used with typescript projects and would like to have code inspection go to the actual lines of typescript code (rather than a definition file).

I can't seem to figure out how to set up an npm project for this.

I have main set properly in package.json

```
{
  // package.json details omitted
  main: "./src/index.ts"
}
```

Upon inspection, I have verified existence of `node_modules/my-project/src/index.ts`.  But when I go to `import * from "my-project";` I get the error:

> Can not find module

---

This seems to indicate it's not possible to have typescript only npm projects, but I'd like to verify that I'm not just making a mistake.

**Is it possible to have a typescript only npm package?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sorry.  It was a stupid mistake, but I still think it's important to have this information easily discoverable.

It is totally possible to create an npm package with only typescript.  If you are having issues with this, it is likely due to a mistake in the set up your package.json.  Double check spelling.

Comment: Where was the spelling issue?

Comment: I think I may have had a `src/index.js` instead of `dist/index.js` or something of that nature.  I just changed a `.ts` to a `.js` and forgot about the path... but I can't remember exactly if that was it.